# Show Your Deleted Questions in Your Activity History (Only Visible to You)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, deleted-questions, profile-page

While working on an alternate question here, I would have loved to see my old question (which had since been deleted by the community).

I know it's available to moderators, would it be possible to leave in our own list (and be flagged as deleted)?

Comment: I think it's a different feature - but it already looks like the entire concept of showing deleted questions was discussed at length here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted

Comment: +1 we should be able to see all our own deleted content.

Comment: @aronchick The feature is already implemented and available for +10k users.

Comment: No, I'm aware it's available for 10k+ users, but I was thinking it'd be possible for all users to see their own. You may want to check the thread showing Jeff's opinion on it - he's vehemently against it.

Comment: Someone needs to make a 10k crawler that will crawl and index every single post ID for all to view. :P:P:P

Comment: 10K users do not have access to this on others' profiles either, @πάνταῥεῖ

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's a strong argument to be made for letting you find *recent* questions that have been deleted - hence the functionality that [Lance describes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272538/show-deleted-questions-in-your-activity-history/272540#272540).

Stuff that was posted months or years ago? Not so much. Some of us have *hundreds* of these posts; rubbing our faces in them long after we've moved on is a recipe for grief. Even the introduction of "recent" functionality has caused some amount of drama from the more... high-strung... members of these sites, as they find themselves unable to move on from their mistakes fast enough. I think we've struck a reasonable balance, but it isn't without compromise on both sides.

Comment: Sigh. Annoying, but it looks like the decision has been made.

Comment: Why do these old deleted questions then count in the question record for the Curious badge or for being banned? There are a lot of posts on meta of the type "I'm banned but I have no deleted questions" ([example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322543/why-am-i-still-banned-from-asking-questions)) and I can't figure out why I haven't earned the Curious badge yet since I can't see my deleted questions. I've posted a feature request for this [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341878/list-of-all-deleted-questions-not-only-recent-ones).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.  Go into your profile and click on the Questions link.  Then scroll to the bottom and click on

[image: Deleted Link]

The deleted questions will be grayed out.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not correct. My question was posted >60 days ago, so it doesn't show up.