# List of all deleted questions, not only recent ones

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, deleted-questions, question-lists

Currently, in the questions tab in the profile page, there is a "deleted recent questions" button:

[image: deleted recent questions]

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244140/recent-deleted-answer-doesnt-show-up-in-my-profile/244144#244144), the questions that appear in this list are only the ones that were posted less than 60 days ago. However, I would like to see a list of all my deleted questions, no matter their age.

If it is not possible to view a list of *all* my own deleted questions, I suggest that the "deleted recent questions" becomes simply "deleted questions". The reason for that is that this may be useful for users who are banned from asking. These users may have asked a lot of bad questions which got deleted, and then two months later come back and notice that they are banned, having forgotten about their bad questions and not being able to find out why they're banned. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322543/why-am-i-still-banned-from-asking-questions) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341036/why-isnt-it-letting-me-ask-a-question) are two of many examples of someone being banned from asking without knowing why since all his deleted questions were old. A moderator had to look at the user's old deleted questions to tell the user why he was banned. If my feature request gets implemented, users will be able to tell themselves why they were banned.

I personally have a similar issue, [and I'm not the only one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286869/have-the-requirements-for-a-positive-question-record-changed). It's not that I'm banned, but I haven't received the Curious badge on Meta because I don't have a positive question record. I recounted my questions to check using the formula from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262817/4284627) and found out that I do have a positive question record, at least with the questions visible on my profile page. That's probably due to some deleted questions, but there is no way I can check since I don't have access to a list of my deleted questions.

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272542/4284627), this feature isn't implemented to allow users to move on from their mistakes, so that they don't get stuck with their mistakes for ever. OK, that's fair enough, but why do these old deleted questions then count for purposes of banning or for the question record (Curious badge)? If it's to allow users to move on from their mistakes, these old deleted questions shouldn't either count for banning or badge purposes.

To conclude, I think that each user should have access to a list of all their own deleted questions that matter for any purpose. Either people should have access to a list of all their deleted questions no matter their age, or old deleted questions shouldn't count for banning purposes, badge purposes or any other purposes. It doesn't make any sense that people get banned or don't have a positive question record for reasons that they can't see.

Comment: Voting to reopen to reconsider feature request - with almost daily "I'm banned but I have no deleted questions" posts on Meta I think it may be time saving measure for moderators. Linked [request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272538/show-your-deleted-questions-in-your-activity-history-only-visible-to-you) closed without discussion if it is useful for banned users. (Post will need to be edited if to include new reasons if reopened).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's true, I will edit to include your point.

Comment: Easiest thing to do is just open the deleted search that.10k users have to all users. I never understood why there was a rep restriction

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341025/show-me-my-own-deleted-questions-and-answers-on-my-profile-page 13 days ago by me was status-declined

Comment: I'm fully in support of this, hence my feature request, but seeing as mine, and every other one I've seen, gets declined I doubt they'll ever implement it.

Comment: I'd love to see that for deleted answers as well

Comment: @Glorfindel No, this question was already closed as a duplicate but it got reopened. Alexei Levenkov's comment explains why.

Comment: That was *another* duplicate. While I agree with the [feature-request], it's of no use having two questions asking for *the exact same thing*, even if it's for partially different reasons. If you can compile a complete list of reasons here, I'm more than happy to vote to close the other questions as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @Glorfindel without a bounty on meta, this is only way to bring new life to an old and declined feature request. I agree with not needing 2 questions but when someone proposes a very well written and popular feature request, it does make some sense to let the new question gain a bit of support. Maybe close thedoor old one as a duplicate of this once it gets an answer

Comment: "Old"? It's barely two weeks old yet.

Comment: @Glorfindel ok, missed that. I thought the dup was the older one that this was originally closed as a dup of. Didn't notice the 2nd closure was a new target